# Send a file to a Telegram Bot with Webhooks

Tags: curl, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm trying to send a file to a Telegram bot through a webhook. I will upload the file (a pdf document) using php and then send a request to the bot webhook to receive the file and do some processing to it.

I'm using Advanced Rest Client (Desktop app) to test this. This is the CURL code that generates:

```
curl "https://mytelegram.bot:8443/notify" \
-X POST \
-d {} \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydGdDH5I9p5ZBfrzu"
```

It returns a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response and I don't know what to do exactly.

I'm using Telegraf framework to build this bot.

Comment: Error would indicate wrong content type, `multipart/form-data` some services restricts to `file` uploads (maybe try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead if not uploading a file)

Comment: I am uploading a file

Comment: Is `https://mytelegram.bot:8443/notify` your bots' registered webhook URL with Telegram?

Comment: I ended up sending the document directly with php to a chat using the sendDocument endpoint.